# XPath to select only certain node based on count

Tags: xpath

I've never been so much familiar with XPath, but is there a way starting from this simplified XML

```
<root>
<item><tag>ABC</tag><description>item1</description></item>
<item><tag>XVY</tag><description>item2</description></item>
<item><tag>RRR</tag><description>item3</description></item>
<item><tag>XVY</tag><description>item4</description></item>
<item><tag>ABC</tag><description>item5</description></item>
<item><tag>ABC</tag><description>item6</description></item>
</root>
```

To get only the items where grouping by tag the count is equal to 3?
In this particular case I should have item1,item5,item6

It's a particular businness logic where I should get only the items where the tag node's value is equal then perform some additional step.

I'll use this Xpath into a C# project, but I think it's not important for this part.

Thanks

Comment: Pure XPath in version 1 is not good at "grouping", XQuery or XSLT are more suitable, unless you can use XPath 3.1 maps or at XPath 2.0 `distinct-values`. So which version of XPath do you use or in which environment, with what kind of software do you use XPath?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.1 (supported by Saxon 9 or 10, Saxon-JS 2, Saxon C/PHP/Python, Altova XML, XmlPrime) you could create maps, merge them and filter by the count:

```
map:merge(
  root/item ! 
  map { tag : . }, 
  map { 'duplicates' : 'combine'}) 
=> map:for-each(function($k, $v) { if (count($v) eq 3) then $v else ()})
```